# How create a child theme for Newspaper theme by themeforest?

Tags: wordpress, installation, themes

I have created two files:

```
style.css
functions.php
```

Both are in the zipped folder `Newspaper-child`.

`style.css`:

```
Theme Name: Newspaper Child
Template: Newspaper
*/
```

`functions.php`:

```
<?php
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles');
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    $parent_style = 'parent-style'; // This is 'twentyfifteen-style' for the Twenty Fifteen theme.
    wp_enqueue_style($parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array($parent_style),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
?>
```

It is messing up my website completely when I use the child theme.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the dependency on 'parent-style'.  Use this code instead.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_enqueue_styles');

function child_enqueue_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), '1.0');
}
```

Comment: Check my answer below. Is it fine now?

Comment: Thanks Andrew. You saved me!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
```

function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_enqueue_styles');
```

function child_enqueue_styles() {

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), '1.0');
```

}
    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );

Is it fine now?